# Not the way I usually look like

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

The answer to this puzzle is... well, you'll notice!

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assembling the pieces

> gives this:
>  [image: cube net]
>
>  This appears to be the net of a cube. And the line traces the letters:
>  `ANESWERIRSYDHICLEUNYDERCPOVA`.

Well, that *almost* looks like a message.

> I'd like to skip that E... and that means that I'd be using these letters to start off:
>  [image: cube net, cells labelled]
>  Hey, that looks like a 6-sided die! And that makes the 2×3 grid make sense: it's representing which face is which.
>  So, labelling the other faces accordingly:
>  [image: cube net, more cells labelled]
>
>  gives **ANSWER IS DICE UNDERCOVA**.

Comment: Everything right, well done!